# Adding Header while unshortening URLs

Tags: python, url, python-requests

For a project of mine I have to unshorten a massive list of URLs scraped from Twitter.
I've looked at a bunch of tutorials and SO questions, and as of now I have structured my code to pick randomly an IP proxy from a free-IP proxy website.
The next step I would like to implement, to avoid IP bans as much as possible, would be to implement a user-agent header.

The code is as follow:

```
def unshorten_url(url):
    """
    Function to unshorten a single URL
    """
    try: r = session.head(url, allow_redirects=True, timeout = 10).url
    except: r = 'Error'
    return r

session = requests.session()
session.proxies.update({'http': proxy})
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)', "Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}
session.headers = headers
unshorten_url(my_url)
```

The code is a bit more sophisticated than this (*e.g. I have a function to pick a random proxy, and I am currently using fake_useragent module to pick a random user-agent*).

**The ISSUE**: If I specify a session header and thus a custom user-agent, my URL will not be unshortened, the function just gives me back my shortened URL. If I do not specify the header, it works as intended.

Thank you for all your help!

*N.B.:* I have also tried with requests.get, the same problem arises. I could avoid entirely specifying the header and hope to avoid too many IP bans, however I'd be curious to understand if I am doing something wrong

Comment: Your `unshorten_url` function will never get to `results[url] = r` as it is after the `return` statement.

Comment: My bad, the results[url] part was a code typo (I stored results in a dictionary). In any case, r should give me the unshortened URL, and it does that IF I do not specify the header of the requests.session. I fixed the code snippet to avoid confusion.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't need the `allow_redirects`, that would result in unnecessary additional requests to the target's server.  Just simply get the location header from the response, e.g. `session.head(url).headers.get('location')`.